# Mongoose 5 suddenly errors "MongoError: unknown string alias for $type: 2dsphere"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-plugins

I were using Mongoose 4.x and everything was fine. Soon I updated it to Mongoose 5.0.1, I started getting this error

```
/Users/me/ExampleCode/example-backend/example-backend-admin/example-backend-admin-places/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:417
    throw err;
    ^
MongoError: unknown string alias for $type: 2dsphere
at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/me/ExampleCode/example-backend/example-backend-admin/example-backend-admin-places/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:45:10)
at /Users/me/ExampleCode/example-backend/example-backend-admin/example-backend-admin-places/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1103:54
at /Users/me/ExampleCode/example-backend/example-backend-admin/example-backend-admin-places/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:541:18
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I never touched the schema for a long while, the only change was updating mongoose, so I'm sure it's where the problem is.

Here's the relevant part in the Mongoose Schema

```
    geometry: {type: String, trim: true, index: {unique: false, name: 'geometry', partialFilterExpression: {geometry: {$type: '2dsphere'}}}},
```

I'm drowning .... save me ....

Comment: Any help please ?

Comment: did you update mongodb too ?

Comment: Yes I upgraded to mongodb 3.0. However, if I simply downgrade mongoose to 4.x it works perfectly fine even with mongodb 3.0

Comment: Are you sure it is 3.0 not 3.4? Well I don't know what mongoose is doing but {$type: '2dsphere'} is not a valid index option and 3.4 mongo version enforces strict index validation so the error.

Comment: Then how do i specify a 2dsphere index in mongoose ?

Comment: Yes, it's the npm package "mongodb": "^3.0.1" link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Comment: Check the mongo db server version not driver. You can run db.version to know version in shell.

Comment: it's version 3.4.7

Comment: for the time being I changed it to partialFilterExpression { geometry : '2dsphere' }

Comment: so maybe you accept my answer cuz my code is equal to this one

Comment: @ByteMaster I will accept your answer once i test that I save a GeoJson successfully in that field

Comment: you know what, it's not how it works. Your question was bout syntax error, so community helped reach out that question, I've been pointed out whats wrong with your code with proofs, so you have another question on your code logic - you create another one. It's a bit rude

Comment: @ByteMaster you're wrong. My question is not necessarily about a syntax error. It could be a syntax error and it could be sth totally different. The answer you provided is not what I am looking for, and you didn't explain how it will accept a GeoJSON value in that field. I provided a model as you requested. Apologies for the delay in testing your answer, once I do, I will then upvote and accept your answer, or downvote it and reject it.  Kindly keep the stackoverflow community in mind, I won't accept a wrong answer. Your answer shows eq '2dsphere' as a value, I need 2dsphere as a type.

Answer (score 0):

As refer to docs for MongoDB - [partial index fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/), the **$type** is refer to *[BSON types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#document-type-available-types)*, [which are existed in Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#op._S_type) and nor your own type, so my point is that you need to change the query for that like

```
partialFilterExpression: {geometry: {$eq: '2dsphere'}}
```

I'm not sure how it could been working previously

Comment: I'm testing your answer as we speak. But what does eq mean ?

Comment: it's mean that **geometry** value should be _equal_ to value **2dsphere**

Comment: It runs fine with no error. I'm yet to test it with saving a geojson in that field. My gut feeling tells me it won't work. But the geometry value should be equal to a value of type '2dsphere' and not equal to the string '2dsphere'

Comment: just read provided links (there are 3 of them) for better understanding. GL

Comment: then provide your model and possibles values. In your meaning type - is what value can be at field geometry. And in Mongo see upper

Comment: here is the model I am trying to save in the field {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[ 0.0,0.0]}